# How do you make a database using sqlite3 in python

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I'm trying to make a .db file which as a 1 to many realntionshp in it and it will not work.

```
from sqlite3 import *
$sqlite3 testDB.db
SQLite version 3.7.15.2 2013-01-09 11:53:05
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite>
CREATE TABLE BOOKS(
ISBN TEXT PRIMARY KEY    NOT NULL,
TITLE            TEXT   NOT NULL,
ATHOUR           TEXT   NOT NULL,
NUMBEROFCOPIES   INT    NOT NULL,
OUTNUMBER        INT    NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE LOANS(
ORDERNUMBER TEXT PRIMATY KEY    NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (ISBN) REFERENCES BOOKS
TILLE                   TEXT    NOT NULL,
AUTHOR                  TEXT    NOT NULL,
PERSON                  TEXT    NOT NULL,
DUEDATE                 TEXT    NOT NULL);
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: (A) Define "will not work".  (B) This question has nothing whatsoever to do with Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at pySQLite. It's a package that will allow you to dev databases within Python use sqlite, but from what I'm seeing, it isn't as widely available.

If I were you, I'd take a good look at using MySQL and then wrapping it with mysql-python.

https://wiki.python.org/moin/MySQL

and

http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/

Will be great places to start. The getting started page on the Google link has some great examples of pulling in a database to Python.

I hope this helps!